# Cell value gets auto replaced by "FALSE"

Tags: google-sheets

This is happening to multiple workbooks inside my Google project management file. I have client #s and client Names. I enter new numbers as I get more clients for my business.

What is happening now is when I enter the client number and then the name, the number automatically turns to `FALSE`.

There is no data validation or formula attached to the client number. Both the columns (client number and client name) are unique are not related.

Why does the `FALSE` value get inserted when I write the client Name? I am an avid Google Sheets user and this is driving me crazy!

Please see the attached screenshot. When I added a new client name (David & Angela) in Column B, column A automatically became `FALSE`. When I added yet another client in Column B (Sharon & Mohan), column A again became `FALSE` even though it was empty before. When I changed Column A to actual number (2020032), column B became `FALSE`.

Is this a bug of some kind?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Did you look at the Script Editor by any chance ?